# FileUpload - RequiredFieldValidator and RegularExpressionValidator do not fire

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, file-upload, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a `FileUpload` control for which I have attached a `RequiredFieldValidator` and a `RegularExpressionValidator`. My code in working fine on my computer, but in production neither the `RequiredFieldValidator` nor the `RegularExpressionValidator` fire. This is very weird to me, I have no explanation for this.

My code is:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="XlsUpload" runat="server" CssClass="TextInput" Width="250" />
<asp:LinkButton id="lbnUploadFile" Runat="server" CssClass="MainLink" ToolTip="Upload File" OnClick="lbnUploadFile_Click">Upload File</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" CssClass="warning" runat="server" ControlToValidate="XlsUpload" ErrorMessage="Please Upload a File!"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" CssClass="warning" runat="server" ControlToValidate="XlsUpload"
                ErrorMessage="Please upload only txt and docfiles" ValidationExpression=".*\.([tT][xX][tT]|[dD][oO][cC])"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

What could be the cause for this?

Comment: Please mention validation group to both upload button and validation controls and see if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works in my case:

```
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="FUFileCurriculum" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ID="FUFileCurriculumValidator" ControlToValidate="FUFileCurriculum" ErrorMessage="Unauthorized file extension" ValidationExpression="^.+\.(?!exe|js|bat).*$" />
```

It avoids the upload of files that ends with exe, js or bat.